# Add exception to regular expression if it happens to be between quotation marks?

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a java application where I'm trying to seperate tokens from each other given a string using regular expressions. the regular expression should seperate symbols (+ - / * = and any kind of brackets) from other things like letters and numbers, however I want to add an exception where it wouldn't seperate these symbols if they happen to be between quotation marks as in a string literal

here is the regular expression I currently have:
`([a-zA-Z0-9"]+|[\(\)\[\]\+\-\*\/\{\}=])`
this pattern gives me different matches and I process each match as a seperate token

if I use this on this example string: `"SomeStr=123"(something)` (including the quotation marks) what I get is these tokens: `["SomeStr, =, 123", (, something, )]`

what I want to get is:`["SomeStr=123", (, something, )]`

the pattern should only seperate the symbols if they were between quotation marks (with the fact that the quotation marks won't always be directly behind/infront of the symbol)
is there a way I can do this in the regex?

FYI I'm trying to do this to make a tokenizer for educational purposes, perhaps using regex isn't the best way to do this?

Comment: You can try this regex: `\"[^\"]*\"|[-()\[\]+*/{}=]|\w+`

Comment: It sounds like you want a custom compiler

Comment: @anubhava wow that was quick! I have no idea how it works but it seems to work perfectly, I should definitly learn more about regular expressions, thanks!

Comment: regular expressions work well if you can find and express strict rules. General tokenization has so many exceptions and special rules that you probably wouldn't use that here. E.g. usually you'll have some form of escaping, `"SomeStr=\"123\""(something)` , maybe a syntax to span your string across multiple lines, ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a regex that matches quoted first as the first alternative before matching symbols and words like this:

```bash
\"[^\"]*\"|[-()\[\]+*/{}=]|\w+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GyW6d2/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\"[^\"]*\"`: Match quoted text
- `|`: OR
- `[-()\[\]+*/{}=]`: Match a given symbol
- `|`: OR
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters

If you want to allow escaped quotes then use:

```bash
\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"|[-()\[\]+*/{}=]|\w+
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/GyW6d2/2)